# Angular aligned checkboxes on 4 columns

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to get angular display a list of responsive checkboxes in 4 columns all aligned starting from the left but the issue is that the columns are not starting from left nor balanced causing some odd results.

Eg I try to have:

```
[] Apples        [] Oranges       []Bananas     [] Kiwis
[] Apples2       [] Oranges2      []Bananas3    [] Kiwis4
[] Apples3       [] Oranges4
```

Currently the output looks like using 3 columns:

```
[] Apples        [] Oranges       []Bananas     
[] Kiwis4        [] Oranges2      []Bananas3    
                 [] Oranges3      [] Kiwis
                 [] Oranges4
```

--> So this is somehow odd

```
<section>
<form novalidate name="form.part3" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p ng-repeat="opt in fruits.slice(0, fruits.length/3)">
            <md-checkbox class="md-default"
                         aria-label="fruits"
                         name="fruits">
                {{opt.name}}
            </md-checkbox>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p ng-repeat="opt in fruits.slice(fruits.length/3, fruits.length/3*2)">
            <md-checkbox class="md-default"
                         aria-label="fruits"
                         name="fruits">
                {{opt.name}}
            </md-checkbox>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p ng-repeat="opt in fruits.slice(fruits.length/3*2, fruits.length)">
            <md-checkbox class="md-default"
                         aria-label="fruits"
                         name="fruits">
                {{opt.name}}
            </md-checkbox>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form tag has class `"col-md-12"`.

This will divide the page into 12 columns.

Inside your form, you have 3 `<div class="col-md-3">` which in total makes 9 columns.

To make four columns(which you mentioned in what you want), you need to have 4 divs with class `"col-md-3"`.

And accordingly you can put data inside those divs. Which could be somethig like below.(Not sure on how you are calculating length)

```
    <form novalidate name="form.part3" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p ng-repeat="opt in fruits.slice(0, fruits.length/4)">
            <md-checkbox class="md-default"
                         aria-label="fruits"
                         name="fruits">
                {{opt.name}}
            </md-checkbox>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p ng-repeat="opt in fruits.slice(fruits.length/4, fruits.length/4*3)">
            <md-checkbox class="md-default"
                         aria-label="fruits"
                         name="fruits">
                {{opt.name}}
            </md-checkbox>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p ng-repeat="opt in fruits.slice(fruits.length/4*3, fruits.length/4*2)">
            <md-checkbox class="md-default"
                         aria-label="fruits"
                         name="fruits">
                {{opt.name}}
            </md-checkbox>
        </p>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-3">
        <p ng-repeat="opt in fruits.slice(fruits.length/3*2, fruits.length*4)">
            <md-checkbox class="md-default"
                         aria-label="fruits"
                         name="fruits">


                {{opt.name}}
                </md-checkbox>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Hey Dheeraj, thanks good catch will try to give it a try. Any idea about the data being randomly split into different columns ? Sometimes I only have one value on the left, 3 in the middle and then 4 on the left side.

ng-show="opt.category_id === selectedCategory || selectedCategory == 'All'"

Comment: You can use *NgIf in div tags to put condition and accordingly put data in those divs.